# UIManagedDocument failing to initialize, Giving me "Ghost Entity" error

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-data

Tried to build a project with a coredata model, got this error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't merge models with two different entities named 'Patient''
```

On a whim, I deleted my coredata model and made a new one with the "Patient" entity renamed to "Noob" and I get word for word the exact same error. The coredata model with "Patient" no longer exists, what gives? Time for a new project?

Answer (score 0):

You can **clean** your project with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and try again.

Comment: ok, did that but no such luck. I'm going to start over (again) and likely that will fix it, but I'm really wondering what the heck is going on. Is it possible that I am getting this error because I've started this project over doing a manual delete and not deleting through the organizer?